# Eleventy nested pages from data

Tags: liquid, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm new to Eleventy and trying to create what seems like a straightforward site structure but I'm struggling so would appreciate any help.

I have the following data:

```
{
  authors: [
    {
      name: "John Smith",
      books: [
        {
          title: "John's book 1",
          price: 9.99
        },
        {
          title: "JS book 2",
          price: 10.99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Mickey Mouse",
      books: [
        {
          title: "Mice to meet you",
          price: 7.99
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With this data I wish to create the following page hierarchy:

```
/authors
/authors/john-smith
/authors/john-smith/johns-book-1
/authors/john-smith/js-book-2
/authors/mickey-mouse
/authors/mickey-mouse/mice-to-meet-you
```

I have created the `/authors`, `/authors/john-smith` and `/authors/mickey-mouse` pages, however, I'm struggling with the "book" pages.

I'm not sure how to create the pages and I also wish to display the author name on the page and can't figure out how to gain access to the data.

e.g. `/authors/mickey-mouse/mice-to-meet-you` should contain the following:

```
<h1>Mice to meet you</h1>
<h2>By Mickey Mouse</h2>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would probably tackle this by creating a [global JavaScript data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-js/) that manipulates your authors data into a list of books:

```js
// _data/books.js (for example)
const data = require('./data.json')

module.exports = function () {
  // `reduce` takes in an accumulator (empty array in this case)
  // and then iterates through the array
  const books = data.authors.reduce((acc, author) => {
    // for every author, we look at every book
    author.books.forEach((book) => {
      // add the book to the new array, adding in the author's name
      acc.push({author: author.name, ...book})
    })
    // return the accumulator for the next iteration
    return acc
  }, [])

  // the data now looks like
  // [ { author: "John Smith", title: "John's book 1", ... }, ... ]
  return books
}
```

We can now [paginate](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/) through this array of books:

```yaml
---
pagination:
  data: books # assuming the data file is books.js
  size: 1
  alias: book
permalink: "/authors/{{ book.author }}/{{ book.title }}/"
---

# {{ book.title }}
## By {{ book.author }}
```

(The above example assumes you're using Markdown with the [Nunjucks template engine](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/config/#default-template-engine-for-markdown-files), but it'll work with whatever you're using.)